# past continuous vs past perfect continuous

Tags: past-continuous, past-perfect-continuous

What is the difference between these two sentences?

I took my car to the garage because it wasn't working properly. This means that at that moment my car wasn't working properly.

I took my car to the garage because it hadn't been working properly. This means that over a period of time it had not been working properly.

Am I correct?

Comment: In English for words like **hadn't** we use the apostrophe or single-quote on the keyboard: **'**  You're using the backtick, which breaks the formatting of your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're correct.

`It hadn't been working` emphasizes that the car had issues for a longer period of time.

Comment: It means that up until the time he took it to the garage, it had not been working right.